# HTML viewer for massive files

Tags: windows, gratis, html, documentation-viewer

We ran a 16 hour regression test last night, which generated its output in HTML.

One colleague has an HTML file which he says no browser can open, presumably because it is so large (they are all just text, with a bit of colo(u)r, nothing fancy; I had thought of exporting to plain text, but, alas, we do relay on colo(u)r to indicate pass/fail (the tool does that & we can't change it; I *suppose* I could run a Python script over it, find the CSS for the failure colo(u)r and insert some text ...)).

My own result file is large, but viewable, but is ***incredibly*** slow to navigate.

So, I am seeking an app which:

- runs in Windows
- is free for commercial use (do we have a tag for that?)
- allows me to view & quickly navigate within humongous HTML files

Comment: What kind of sizes (in MB)?

Comment: Nothing major; less than 10 mB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a not so well known browser called [Links](http://links.twibright.com/) I've used it to open 30+ MB files. Its a bit slow at first (loading) but then you can view the file relatively quick. But resizing the window tends to make it reload.

Comment: Welcome aboard. That's a good answer, and I like that you have used it & can give your experience. You didn't address the licensing, but I checked and it's FOSS, so I presume it will be fine for commercial use. Welcome aboard; I look forward to your future contributions to the site ;-)